# Sitecore 8 Component MV testing

Tags: sitecore, ab-testing, sitecore8

How to start a component test in Sitecore 8?

In sitecore7.5 there was a button Start Test on the ribbon, now under the Optimizaion menu in Experience Editor there are Lists section and Create a page test. But not Start test button.

Just to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I've an Item that has a rendering in Presentation Details. On that rendering there is a MV test defined. I would like to start this test.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore 8 now has new A/B testing features.

In the Page Editor (Experience Editor) there is an Optimization tab. Here you can Click "Start a Test". Instead of just being able to test certain controls individually you can now test a complete variation of a page.

You then go to the Experience Optimization option on the Dashboard to see how well your variations are performing.

You can still test individual components in the Page Editor as before by clicking on the component and selecting the "Test a component" option in the ribbon above the component.

Comment: So do you mean that I need to create a page test after defining some component tests and then start this page test. It that correct?

Comment: I've double checked this - There is still the option to test components on their own. You have to click on the component in the Experience editor and there is an option for you to test on the ribbon on each component - (it's two window icons). You can then use the same variations using the rules engine as before. When you save it should say you have components that have test in the top menu. You then need to deploy the tests from the workbox.

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 8 you should run the component test using the workflow command "Approve with test". Take a look at this [document](https://doc.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20experience%20platform/content%20testing/adding%20content%20testing%20to%20a%20workflow)